# Why i cannot select payment type in google Cloud platform?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, credit-card, billing

I am programmer and i was given the google account with billing card added. But i cannot add billing account in google platform.
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: For questions such as these, it is best if you file a support ticket to them directly here: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. They will be able to address all your concerns regarding billing, pricing, free trial and setting limits.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that you aren't granted permissions to select the billing account
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

Comment: if i get it right, roles can be added in business account, but it was created as personal account.